# Literal string works but string doesn't in file.open()

Tags: c++, file-io

This works:

```
file.open("Levels\\test.txt");
```

This doesn't:

```
string pathname = "Levels\\test.txt";
file.open(pathname);
```

It outputs the following error:

```
no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstrea<char, std::char_traits<char> >::open
(std::string&)'
```

Comment: Making us guess what type `file` is, eh?

Comment: Since the other call worked, I didn't think it was relevant. It is an ifstream.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That member function takes a `char const*`, not a `std::string`; you would need to pass it `pathname.c_str()`.

(In C++0x, there is an overload of `open` that takes a `std::string`, so your code will someday work as is; your implementation apparently does not support this yet.)